# XIB file is fitted with whole screen in iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have been trying to show `UIViewController` on the whole screen while using the present modal?

here is the output image

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have xib viewController where I am trying to send value to another viewController using the present method but it does not fit fullscreen.

Here is the code :

```
let vc = TabBarViewController()
vc.processDefID = keyVal

vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen //or .overFullScreen for transparency
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

ANother mehtod tried:

```
 var clientView: UIViewcontroller

 let V = TabBarViewController()
            self.clientView?.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            self.clientView?.addChild(V)
            self.clientView?.view.addSubview(V.view)
            V.processDefID = keyVal
        V.view.frame = (self.clientView?.view.bounds)!
            V.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
            V.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
            self.present(V, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: You mean to say that you wanted to present another viewcontroller (fullscreen) with value passing?

Comment: Exactly , now i can able to pass value but screen is fitted. you can see my screenshot

Comment: what do you mean by screen is fitted?

Comment: i tried that too it does not fitted to fullscreen

Comment: @matt how can i fix this.. i tried another by declaring uiviewcontroller and added as subview. But it gettting crash at self.client.view.bounds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally you can show/present your view in two way.

Create `UIViewController` object and present it in the way you are doing

```
func presentView() {
  let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScannerViewController")        
  vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
  vc.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
  vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
  self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

In the case of using `UIViewController` with `XIB` file, it will just change the ViewController initialisation part and nothing else, just like

```
let vc = ScannerViewController(nibName: "ScannerView", bundle: nil)
```

Create `UIViewController` object and insert it in the following way, you can also assign the custom frame to it's `UIView` object.

```
func presentView() {
                let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ScannerViewController")
                vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height/2)
                vc.view.backgroundColor = .red
                self.addChild(vc)
                self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
              }
```

Comment: here i am using xib uiviewcontroller

Comment: If you are using xib uiviewcontroller then it will just change your uiviewcontroller initialisation and nothing else. Updated the answer accordingly, please check!!